# python script not working show tag from instance

Tags: boto3

any idea why I cannot see the tag name from this. actually nothing is showing up

```
import boto3

def get_instance_name(fid):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    ec2instance = ec2.Instance(fid)
    instancename = ''
    for tags in ec2instance.tags:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tags["Value"]
    return instancename

get_instance_name("i-045723ac1bf218865")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it working with this

```
import boto3
import sys
import argparse
instance_id = sys.argv[1]

def print_ec2_tagname(instance_id):
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-west-1")
    ec2instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
    instancename = ''
    for tags in ec2instance.tags:
        if tags["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tags["Value"]
    #return instancename
    print (instancename)

print_ec2_tagname(instance_id)
```